# App is not listed in vivo autostart activity

Tags: java, android

i want my app to autostart in vivo device but when i try to do so my app does not show in the list .Can anyone tell me how to resolve this error

i am already able to redirect to autostart activity of vivo

```
 if (Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("vivo")) {

                TITLE = "vivo device detected";
                PACKAGE_NAME = "com.vivo.permissionmanager";
                PACKAGE_ACITIVITY = "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity";
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                        PACKAGE_NAME, PACKAGE_ACITIVITY));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Comment: did you found any thing regarding this?

Comment: @ManthanPatel nope

Comment: have you found any solution yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//Please add this receiver in android manifest file

```
<receiver
        android:name=".Boot_BroadCast"
        android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        </intent-filter>

</receiver>

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build.VERSION;

public class Boot_BroadCast extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    intent = new Intent(context, Clap_Service.class);
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        context.startForegroundService(intent)
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. It will work on 80% Chinese manufacturing devices

```
    private void checkBatteryOptimization() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        String packageName = this.getPackageName();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName))
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
            else {
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
            }
        }
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void addAutoStartup() {

        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
            if ("xiaomi".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
            } else if ("oppo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
            } else if ("vivo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
            } else if ("Letv".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe", "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity"));
            } else if ("Honor".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));

            } else if ("oneplus".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.oneplus.security", "com.oneplus.security.chainlaunch.view.ChainLaunchAppListActivity"));
            }
//            case "oneplus":
//                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.oneplus.security", "com.oneplus.security.chainlaunch.view.ChainLaunchAppListAct‌​ivity"));
//                break;
            List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            if (list.size() > 0) {
                startActivityForResult(intent, 9);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("exc", String.valueOf(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.e("test123 ee", "test " + requestCode + " " + resultCode + " " + data);
        if (requestCode == 9) {
 Intent mainIntent = new Intent(NotificationsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello friend, I have the same problem with VIVO devices. Could you post all your code, it's missing some things like the 'addAutoStartup' call